# Правда ли что использование статических переменных это плохо?

Tags: c++, static

Плохо ли использование статических переменных. Читал, что они замедляют выполнение программы, так ли это?

Comment: В смысле замедления - впервые слышу. Другое дело, что они вносят излишнее связывание, как и, например, глобальные переменные. Опять же, это тоже не повод полностью от них отказываться. Всякому инструменту - его задачи (и наоборот).

Comment: Ну, некоторое замедление static-переменные внести всё-таки могут. Т.к. инициализация static-переменной является потокобезопасной, то в общем случае компилятор должен добавить некоторые примитивы синхронизации, дабы эту самую потокобезопасность при инициализации обеспечить. Но так происходит не всегда. Иногда оптимизатору удаётся выкрутиться и обойтись без синхронизации. См.: [Оптимизация инициализации статических переменных внутри функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1209877).

Comment: Даже если накладные расходы всё-таки есть, то это не повод тут же отказаться от static-переменных. Очень вероятно, что это окажется «экономией на спичках». Также не забывайте про такую полезную штуку, как `thread_local`-переменные.

Comment: В c++, если статическаие переменные  внутри функции инициализированы **не нулями**, то немного замедляют (при входе в нее происходит проверка, инициализированы ли они). В Си не замедляют.

Comment: @avp, вот ещё наткнулся на такую [статью](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/527044/) в интернете. Цитирую: `Статические переменные медленнее, чем нестатические переменные. Для того, чтобы обратиться к статической переменной, нам нужно сделать несколько дополнительных действий, таких как переход в другой сегмент памяти.` Если честно, мне кажется это бред, ведь доступ в .data сегмент осуществляется так-же как, например в стек, при помощи адресации по памяти. Все эти сегменты это просто условное деление памяти и никаких накладок по производительности сегментация не несёт, верно ли это?

Comment: @n1kzzz, насколько мне известно, да, в большинстве случаев, в gnu/linux это верно (про windows не знаю)